Python Walrus in Generator (filter)
i have been using python "walrus" operator := quite a while
yet
I can not make up any articulated explanation on why it does not work like below
def tallest_ppl(**kwargs):
    tallest = filter(lambda pair: pair[1] == (max_height := max(kwargs.values())), kwargs.items())
    return '\n'.join(f'{person} : {max_height}' for person, height in sorted(tallest))
res = tallest_ppl(Wilson=185, Jackie=176, Saersha=165, Abram=169, Roman=185)
print(res)

the task is to display tallest sortedmax_height is in particular problem causing variable
I am aware below works fine
...
tallest = filter(lambda pair: pair[1] == max(kwargs.values()), kwargs.items())
return '\n'.join(f'{person} : {height}' for person, height in sorted(tallest))

but what causing walrus err?
is it lambda return be a place of walrus incorrect application? I am really stuck
On the contrary in the below example all is fine "walrus"-wise
from collections import defaultdict


def tallest_people(**kwargs):
    d, s = defaultdict(list), '%s : %.f'
    [d[height].append(person) for person, height in kwargs.items()]
    return '\n'.join(sorted(map(lambda name: s % (name, max_height), d.get(max_height := max(d))))))


What walrus error?

Except in a comprehension or generator expression, := assigns names in the current scope, just like any other assignment. You can see the spec here.
filter is not a comprehension or generator expression. In your failing code, the scope the := assigns in is that of the function created by the lambda, not the scope of the tallest_ppl function. You're assigning a local variable in the nested function, but trying to use it in the outer function.
You shouldn't use := for this anyway. Recomputing max_height on every iteration of the filter is wasteful. Compute it once, up front:
max_height = max(kwargs.values())
tallest = filter(lambda pair: pair[1] == max_height, kwargs.items())

Note that this will throw a ValueError if kwargs is empty. How you want to handle empty kwargs is up to you - maybe a ValueError is appropriate, or maybe you want to return '', or do something else.

yes it is surely wasteful I just could not figure out - I did miss out the scope now makes perfect sense thanks!
